# video.js Chrome and FF Quality problems

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html5-video, video.js

I can't work out why my video is playing at different qualities on different browsers. In Chrome and FF the quality is terrible but in Safari and IE it looks fine. Does anyone know of a reason/solution?

Video:
www.mediaeclipse.co.uk

HTML Code:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="1000" height="536" poster="http://www.mediaeclipse.co.uk/Media/previewimage1.png"
 data-setup="{}">
<source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.mediaeclipse.co.uk/Media/Showreel.ogg">
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.mediaeclipse.co.uk/Media/showreelsmall.mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two videos of incredibly different quality. The mp4 rendition looks fine, which is what Safari and IE are playing, but since Chrome and FF can play back OGG natively you're seeing the horrendous OGG encoding.

You can either remove the OGG rendition altogether and let Video.js fallback to the flash player, or transcode the mp4 as an OGG using something like [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) or [Zencoder](http://zencoder.com). I personally would suggest the latter, but either should do the trick.

Comment: That's great thanks! I've created a new, better quality OGG and everything seems to work perfectly!