# How come Video.js would rapidly rotate quality selection?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am loading `videojs` with this config:

```js
const VIDEO_JS_CONFIG = {
  src: 'http://mymanifest.com/manifest.m3u8',
  type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
  controls: true,
  autoplay: true,
  playsinline: true,
  preload: 'auto',
  fullscreen: true,
  liveui: true,
  html5: {
    hls: {
      overrideNative: true
    }
  }
  controlBar: {
    children: {
      playToggle: true,
      progressControl: true,
      customControlSpacer: true,
      volumePanel: true,
      fullscreenToggle: true
    }
  },
};
```

When I view an RTMP stream that just started, I can see the quality rapidly flicker between highest and lowest resolution. I saw this question: [video.js Chrome and FF Quality problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470599/video-js-chrome-and-ff-quality-problems) and had tried `overrideNative` and still see the same behavior.

When we tried using https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-quality-levels, the selector works and selecting a quality sticks to something good. However the `auto` behavior goes back to flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried DASH with segment seconds lower than 2. At 1 second, all sorts of weird things started to happen. 1 would be acceptable for DASH, but not HLS.